# Como consigo criar através do CSS setas que ligam diversas box, como por exemplo os mapas mentais do mindmeinster?

Tags: css

Eu estou fazendo um projeto do qual preciso facilitar a demonstração dos fluxos de vendas.

Consegui criar isso até agora:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que da maneira que eu fiz não tem como deixar a criação desses processos dinâmicos, principalmente os processos alternativos...

Eu preciso de ajuda para entender como seria uma boa maneira para fazer essas setas ligando uma box a outra? (não precisa ser setas iguais a minha)

Comment: Acredito que a melhor solução seja com JS e Canvas... Infelizmente só com CSS vc não vai conseguir muito dinamismo nas coisas... Agora se for só para desenhar gráficos estáticos sugiro que use SVG, ou até clip-path dependendo se for algo mais simples com poucas setas e angulos

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback, você conhece algum exemplo utilizando essas duas formas citadas?

Comment: Aqui tem um modelo, vc pode montar os vetores no Figma e depois exportar o SVG https://www.figma.com/resources/assets/ux-flow-2/ (não precisa ser esse existem outros similares vc tem que pesquisar). Sobre o Canvas acho que seria melhor vc procurar algum plugin de jQuery aqui tem alguns https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/117/top-5-best-sketchpads-and-manually-drawing-on-canvas-javascript-and-jquery-plugins